# Is epi(max(f,g)) the intersection of epi(f) and epi(g)?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

On an exam, I found the question "is max($f(x),g(x))$" convex if $f,g$ are convex?

This lead me to the question in the topic. Is the intersection of epi$(f)$ and epi$(g)$ = epi($\max(f,g)$)? If so, the maximum of two convex functions must be convex. I think.

Comment: You're correct on all counts! Great observation about the epigraphs.